# How to change alpine.js x-text element content based on ajax result?

Tags: ajax, alpine.js

I'm looking into alpine.js and I can't figure out how to set x-text value from another js script later when that value is available (like ajax) In the example I did not use ajax to make it as simple as possible yet same effect.
I have x-text element and want to change it's content in data() later.

```
<html lang="en" x-data="data()">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer=""></script>
    <script>
        function data() {
            return {
                userEmail:'***',//value replaced on load
                setEmail(newValue) {
                    console.log(newValue);//passed value needs to be set as new value
                    this.userEmail = newValue;
                }
            }
        }
        let fn = (newValue)=>{
            data().setEmail(newValue);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div x-text="userEmail">loaded value</div>
    <button onclick="fn('new value here')">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you even try to trigger the `setEmail` function? `x-on:click="setEmail('new value')"`. Codewise this looks like it should work

Comment: I can change the value with x-on:click="setEmail('new value')" yes. But I need to change it with javascript (after I load data from ajax)

Comment: I see I completely missed that `fn` function first time around. If you can just call your ajax request from within the Alpine data, and set the email value on response. If that's not possible, dispatch an event from your ajax script and process that using your Alpine script.

Comment: Thanks for trying @Yinci I did not figured this out. I can always call x-text="fn(value)" and that works, just if is async and the value comes later on, I do not know how to send it to alpine userEmail() function. Hopefully eventually someone will help.

Comment: Could you share your ajax script?

Comment: I did not share it, as it is not important. whatever ajax script does, the result calls function with string. So it's same as clicking on button and calling fn(string);

Comment: As I said before, dispatch an event and listen for it in Alpine. You don't want to share your script, fine, but then I can't help you any further.

Comment: It is not that I don't want to share it. It is just long and complicated. The script I shared has same problem. If it can be fixed there, that's all I need to know. I always try to share just bare minimum, not because I don't want to show my script, but because it is better for whoever goes through it. But yes, I will see that dispatch. Thank you!